# Can't bind Discord.js bot commands to specific channels

Tags: discord, discord.js

I can't find any way to fix having all commands available to all channels. I'm creating a bot
that allows you to play "arcade" games in Discord.

```
...
client.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (message.channel.id != config.singleChannelID) return; // I tried using this, as recommended by other users but I don't know where to put ChannelID.

    let prefixd = 'd!'
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefixd)) return

    let command = msg.content.toLowerCase().slice(prefixd.length).split(" ")[0]

    if (command == '20') msg.channel.send(`You rolled a(n) **${Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1}**!`)
    if (command == '12') msg.channel.send(`You rolled a(n) **${Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1}**!`)
    if (command == '8') msg.channel.send(`You rolled a(n) **${Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1}**!`)
    if (command == '6') msg.channel.send(`You rolled a(n) **${Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1}**!`)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have in there will work, but you need to either store the desired channel ID somewhere (config in your example) or just hard code it if that is acceptable for your needs:

```
if (msg.channel.id != SomeChannelsIdGoesHere) return;
```

If you don't know how to get the channel ID, consult the [discord support pages](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-)

Also, note that you used the identifier 'message' instead of 'msg' as it appears in your event callback.